# 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

After I installed Python and Djangom, I'm trying to use `virtualenv` for django project purpose using virtualenv. I installed virtualenv using pip.

```
pip install virtualenv # got install successfully
```

When I tried to run it, I got the error message

```
C:\Users\gshiv\Desktop\DjangoProject>virtualenv
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

steps:
 - go to where you want create django app on that folder.

then run this command on command prompt : `python -m virtualenv .`

(eg.  C:\Users\gshiv\Desktop\django>python -m virtualenv .)

where django is the my folder i want run virtualenv and .(dot) indicates virtualenv install all it's folder in django folder otherwise you can use other folder name instead .(dot) this time virtulenv creates a folder in main folder(django) .

- after running this command: run `.\scripts\activate` now you can see this type of line on cmd-prompt `(django) C:\Users\gshiv\Desktop\django>`
- i.e main folder name before the source path. now you can install any modules for your project that belongs to that main folder only.

pip install django works fine.

Answer (score 51):

If you can not find your `virtualenv` command in the windows console/terminal after installing it with `pip`, try this to make your environment

```
python -m virtualenv <nameOfEnv>
```

If you want to use a specific version of python, initialize it like this

```
python -m virtualenv <nameOfEnv> -p=<C:/path/to/python/version3.x.x/python.exe>
```

When using windows for first installation, you can use python from WindowsApp

Answer (score 44):

Run `pip uninstall virtualenv` and then `pip install virtualenv`

Comment: I had similar problem, found this SO question.
Then noticed this error message.

WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\bmt\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.

add the dir to the environment path, edit cmd and re-enter cmd.

also: use which to identify what PATH is doing. ie


which python

Comment: Sometimes, re-install is the way to solve the issue :D. Thank you guy

Comment: Second time install virtualenvv as `root` or on windows open terminal/cmd using "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 25):

There are three points that you need to consider:

- Make sure that in the windows **PATH variable** there is an entry with your python installation and the scripts subfolder eg: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\`
- When using `pip install virtualenv`, make sure that you **run `cmd` as administrator**. Otherwise, there might an access denied error during installation and virtualenv will not be installed properly.
- Make sure that virtualenv has been installed correctly. Check in the python scripts subfolder - there must exist an .exe named `virtualenv.exe`. If not, uninstall will `pip uninstall virtualenv` and install again.

Comment: Making sure that I was running in cmd (not powershell) as admin, I uninstalled virtualenv and reinstalled it. Worked like a charm

Comment: For some reason, open the cmd as administrator, then *uninstall" the virtualenv and install again has work for me too.

Answer (score 17):

When I ran the `pip install virtualenv` command I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\directory\to\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
```

so I tried forcing upgrade:

```
pip install --upgrade --force virtualenv
```

Answer (score 14):

`py -3 -m venv venv`

try using the above command.

`virtualenv venv`

will work on only older version of python

Answer (score 13):

Use

```
python -m venv abc
```

Where abc is the name of the virtual environment

Comment: Despite having only 2 upvotes, this was the only answer on this page that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I'm happy to hear that :D

Answer (score 10):

Run CMD as administrator and then enter

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

then re-run CMD as administrator and run

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: You may want to fix spelling of virtualenv from `virualenv` to `virtualenv`

Answer (score 4):

- **Step 1**: Run `pip uninstall virtualenv`.
- **Step 2**: Run `pip install virtualenv`.
- **Step 2.1**: Run `virtualenv` to check if it's now working...
- **Step 3**: Still not working? Go to your prevouis console log to find where it says "WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in
  'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts' which
  is not on PATH."
- **Step 4**: Copy the specified path from the warning message.
- **Step 5**: Search for and open "System Properties" on your PC.
- **Step 6**: Click the Advance tab, and then the Environment Variables Button on the bottom right.
- **Step 7**: Click the variable value "Path" and then click edit.
- **Step 8**: In the Edit Environment variable window, click new then paste your path in any slot.
- **Step 9**: MAKE SURE you click OK twice and not to just exit out.
- **Step 10**: Reboot terminal and check again.

Answer (score 3):

Use `py -m virtualenv Your_Folder_Name`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to reinstall virtualenv. First of all you need to uninstall virtualenv with this command.

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

Then just reinstall with this command.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

**Solution-1:** ***python -m venv name_of_virtual_environment***

```
E:\code\python\tvenv>python -m venv myenv

E:\code\python\tvenv>cd myenv\Scripts\

E:\code\python\tvenv\myenv\Scripts>activate.bat

(myenv) E:\code\python\tvenv\myenv\Scripts>deactivate.bat
E:\code\python\tvenv\myenv\Scripts>
```

**Solution-2:** ***py -3 -m venv name_of_virtual_environment***

```
E:\code\python\tvenv>py -3 -m venv myenv

E:\code\python\tvenv>cd myenv\Scripts

E:\code\python\tvenv\myenv\Scripts>activate.bat

(myenv) E:\code\python\tvenv\myenv\Scripts>deactivate.bat
E:\code\python\tvenv\myenv\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 2):

To install to a specific folder e.g `E:\publish`

`pip install virtualenv`

`virtualenv` .

Comment: How does that install to a specific folder?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run

```
    PowerShell.exe -command "./venv/Scripts/activate"
```

Comment: Hi, there are already 18 other answers on the topic. How does your answer build up on the other answers that already propose similar means to activate venv?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas In my case "./venv/Scripts/activate" doesn't work if you run it from cmd. So there is a prefix "PowerShell.exe -command"  which indicate usage of PowerShell. This was a solution in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For windows
First, install -> `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`
Then setup ->  `mkvirtualenv myproject`
Then you see the list of virtual environment
To see it you write-> `lsvirtualenv`
For working this environment we write -> `workon myproject`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue using python3.

The solution was to use the `python3 -m virtualenv .` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing `virtualenv.exe` from its absolute path, like in my case i found it in `C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe`.

I tried this and it worked, here refer the logs as follows:

Using base prefix `c:\\users\\<user>\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32`
New python executable in `C:\somedir\dir2\dir3\ML_1\ml\env\Scripts\python.exe`
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

Answer (score 0):

This almost works for all

1. Open Command Prompt, navigate it to the Envs folder, run `"env_name\Scripts\activate"`
2. Check whether `virtualenv` is installed or not, if not install it:

   - `pip install virtualenv`
   - `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`
3. Game On. Check on your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too but I figure it out.
you just have to open PowerShell as administrator and then write following command `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted` then type `A`. you are all set!
now uninstall the packages and re-install them.
Now if you write `flask --version` or `virtualenv --version` There will be no error at all.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows

If you want to use the `lsvirtualenv` command with `virtualenv`, follow the steps below.

Incorrect:

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

```
python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Correct:

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

```
python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

## Basic Uses

Then, to create a virtual environment:

```
mkvirtualenv youVirtualEnvironmentName
```

- It will be activated automatically:

  ```
  C:\Users\YourUserName (youVirtualEnvironmentName) λ
  ```

First, to access an existing virtual environment:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName λ workon youVirtualEnvironmentName
```

Next, to exit the currently active virtual environment:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName (youVirtualEnvironmentName) λ deactivate
```

Finally, to list all your virtual environments:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName λ lsvirtualenv

dir /b /ad 'C:\Users\YourUserName\Envs'
==================================================================
youVirtualEnvironmentName
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me:

python -m virtualenv virtualenvname

However, after creating a virtual environment, I could not install any package into it and was getting error: "ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv."

To resolve that, I have had to update the pyvenv.cfg file from the virtual environment folder as below:

include-system-site-packages = true

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14327

---

Update

---

I ran into all sorts of issues like not able to run django-admin command. I have installed python 3.10 from windows store as running python command was taking me to windows store. I already had python 3.11 hence I uninstalled 3.10 and then:

I have found that the path for my python installation was not added into my environment variables (PATH).

- I have added the path for my python installation and closed any existing command prompt (To allow it to use new environment variables)
- Deleted the existing django environment and created it again simply using command: "virtualenv virtualenvname" and it worked for me this time.
- Activate the evironment: virtualenvname\Scripts\activate
- django-admin command worked for me this time.

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, the problem is that I had install `virtualenv` using a normal user.

Switch to Admin or Administrator (if using Windows OS), then run

`pip uninstall virtualenv`
and
`pip install virtualenv`

Close the Admin or Administrator terminal and open the terminal with your normal user and run

```
virtualenv myenv
```

It should create the python virtual environment successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that `virtualenv` has been installed correctly. Check in the python scripts subfolder - there must exist an `.exe` named `virtualenv.exe`. If not, uninstall will `pip uninstall virtualenv` and install again.

Answer (score -1):

1)First Way as

***python -m virtualenv name_of_virtual_environment***

---

**OR**

---

2)Second Way as

***py -3 -m venv name_of_virtual_environment***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is the same as the other, older answers.

Answer (score -2):

1. Open a cmd or ps with run as admin.
2. Now run pip uninstall virtual.
3. pip install virtual.
4. Done :D

Implementation:

1. Go to the directory where you want to make a python env.
2. type: virtualenv myEnv
3. beep bop boop done.

ps: Always use cmd or powershell with run as admin if you're installing some new package.