# Python 3.6 . 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x

I am using advanced Python as well as Pycharm (Up to date as of 2017) when I am using pip/virtual env install.

I got this error:

> 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Could advise a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: use `python3.6 -mvenv my-virtual-env` instead of `virtualenv my-virtual-env`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can u elaborate clearly because I am new to this

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950740/virtualenv-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-prog)

Answer (score 4):

You need to install `virtualenv` using `pip` (pip installs packages)

Open command prompt and type:

```
pip install virtualenv.
```

Good luck.

Comment: It is installed as a sub package while installing `virtualenvwrapper`. So why install separately.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem using **Python 3.7.3** on **Windows 10 - 64 Bit** and in my case it turned out that I had installed the incorrect version of the virtualenvwrapper. I had used the command

`pip install virtualenvwrapper`

which installed successfully but If you're on Windows you need to make sure you run this command

`pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`

with the "-win" at the end.

I had to reinstall it and after that my command `mkvirtualenv project_name` worked fine.

Hope this is useful to someone else out there.

Comment: I had already installed virtualenvwrapper-win but doing it again fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. I am also using Python 3.7.3 and used **pip install virtualenv** first. With this I did not have mkvirtualenv or workon in the Python Scripts folder. Once I ran the **pip install virtualwrapper-win** both bat files were added to my 3.7.3 scripts folder.

Comment: That works when done right.  My bat files ended up in local working directory the first time I tried it :-(

Answer (score 3):

Commands:-

```
md MLTestProject
cd MLTestProject
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
python -m virtualenv testenv
```

Comment: Where did Django come into the question?

Comment: This is great answer.  Command virtualenv did not work for me directly. I had to use `python -m`

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if `virtualenv` scripts are not copied to Python installation directory properly when installing `virtualenv` on Windows

Run CMD as administrator and then enter

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

then re-run CMD as administrator and run

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked well for me:

1. `pip install virtualenv`
2. `pip install virtualwrapper-win`
3. `mkvirtualenv project_name`

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 . 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

- create a virtual environment and activate

  pip install virtualenv

virtualenv name_of_project

or

```
py -3 -m venv name_of_project
```