# Flask python framework installation

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have been trying to install and run it but it's not working.

I am suppose to create a virtual environment first in my working folder I was able to install virtualenv in python-scripts folder. I am using cmd line in Windows.

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\python\Scripts>pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\admin\python\lib\site-packages (16.0.0)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\ADMIN\python\Scripts>cd..

C:\Users\ADMIN\python>cd..

C:\Users\ADMIN>cd desktop

C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop>cd flask_bookreview

C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\flask_bookreview>virtualenv flask
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950740/virtualenv-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-prog)

Answer (score 0):

Read this link to install and activate your virtual enviroment:

http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html

when you successfully install and activate your virtual environment then run this command to install flask:-

> pip install flask

Answer (score 0):

try the answer of Manish Mahendru if you want to install it manually, but if you just want it too work, take a look at Anaconda ([www.anaconda.com/download/](http://www.anaconda.com/download/)).
It contains a ton of useful packages and every one I've used (till now) is already installed with it. flask is installed too.

Answer (score 0):

For creating virtual environment you have to do,

`python -m venv flaskenv`

Now activate the virtualenv like

`cd flaskenv`

`Scripts\activate.bat`

Now install as

`(flaskenv) C:/User/ADMIN/> pip install flask`

Comment: Thank so much. It worked fine. Guess I was not getting the syntax right especially the addition of .bat to "activate" .