# Can't Create Virtualenv in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, virtualenv, command-prompt

So I'm trying to create an app that uses the text recognition of the Google API and I am alright in python3 but still very beginner skill wise with programming so I don't know what's going on. I just followed all the steps and even created a system variable to put the scripts folder in my PATH or whatever. My problem is as I was trying to follow the steps in the provided picture[These are the instructions that the Google documentation is giving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q7cB.png), I encountered the problems in the second picture of the command prompt [Here are the errors I'm seeing in the command prompt when I input the stuff that the Google Documentation said to put.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT3YD.png). I really need help to complete this and please also tell me exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950740/virtualenv-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-prog)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtualenv` is probably not installed yet. You can do this with `pip3 install virtualenv`. `pip3` is bundled with Python starting from version 3.4, but if you don't have it, see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/.

If you are sure `virtualenv` is indeed installed, it is likely not on the system path. Use `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path\here` and replace `C:\your\path\here\` with the location of `virtualenv.exe`.

Comment: Nope, It's installed

Comment: Is `virtualenv.py` in you system PATH?

Comment: I have the scripts directory in the PATH and that folder has virtualenv.exe

Comment: Try reinstalling `virtualenv` from cmd with admin provileges.

Comment: Use `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall virtualenv`

Comment: That worked and actually did more but now it says virtualenv.exe is installed in C:\.. stuff....\python37-32\Scripts which is not on a PATH. What's the best way to fix this because I've tried fixing the path but I wasn't able to

Comment: How did you try fixing the path?

Comment: I think I added a system variable called pythonpath that went to the scripts folder in Python

Comment: Run `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path\here\` and replace C:\your\path\here\ with the location of virtualenv.exe

Comment: Can you show me what directory do I run that in and what exactly I put in the your path here. And I'm gonna have to get off and not respond for a while to do homework.

Comment: Any directory, just on the command line. And replace C:\your\path\here\ with where you said virtualenv was installed (C:\.. stuff....\python37-32\Scripts)

Comment: Set path is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Shouldn't happen, because `set` is a built-in windows command. Make sure there is a space between `set` and `PATH`

Comment: Ohh that was the problem, I think I just saw the PATH=% Part connected and just subconsciously connected the whole beginning.

Comment: I haven't used stack overflow much do you mean add solved to the beginning of the title like you normally do with any types of forums. Also I will make sure to refer to you sometimes if I have a question since I am trying to gain more connections with good programmers

Answer (score 2):

instead of using 
`virtualenv venv`

try

`py -3 -m venv venv`

to create virtual environment

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/installation/

Answer (score 0):

py -3 -m venv venv worked for me on my Windows, after I also did rest of the suggestions like reinstall virtualenv and setting up the path. Now, I can see the venv folder in my working directory.