# Problems with Python and Virtual Environments, beginner programmer on Windows 10

Tags: python, shell, cmd, pip, virtualenv

I'm a relatively new programmer trying to use Python with pip and virtual environments, and Python and pip are working just fine; however, I'm having some serious troubles with the Virtual environments. For starters, I'm on a Windows 10 PC with Python 3.8.1 installed, and I've been using both CMD and Shell to try to get this working. I successfully installed virtualenv with pip, and any time I try to reinstall it I get this error:

> ```
> Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\[myname]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (16.7.9)
> ```

So I know I have it installed, but whenever I try to access it in the way that literally every tutorial I've seen, I get this error:

```
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I get this error even when I try to check the version of virtualenv, but it keeps saying that I do have it downloaded. I've been searching for an answer for days now-- I've uninstalled and reinstalled everything, I've been messing with my PATH settings, and I've run multiple versions of commands, but nothing is working. Does anyone have any sort of advice?

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950740/virtualenv-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-prog)

Comment: This kind of question has been asked many times already. Here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48321639/11301900.

Answer (score 0):

Add `C:\users\[myname]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Scripts` to `PATH` and restart cmd consoles.

Comment: Instead of `C:\users\[myname]` I'd recommend to use `%UserProfile%`...

Comment: Instead of `C:\users\[myname]\appdata\local`, I'd recommend `%LocalAppData%`. I would also mention, as I didn't see it mentioned in the links above, that it appears from your directory name that there may even be an x64/x86 issue. Please do some research and then update your post with all of the steps you've taken. In order for us to help, it is easier if we can replicate your environment.