# Error after installing virtualenv on vscode

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am new to programming and I encountered this error after I installed `virtualenv` in my vscode. Please, help me.

```
virtualenv : The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ virtualenv myprojectenv
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950740/virtualenv-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-prog)

Comment: As a beginner, your first step should be to google the error message. For example, you would find the above link that already answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you just type in `virtualenv myproject` in the powershell or command prompt, it doesn't know what program that code actually relates to in any way (and it isn't a code it recognizes.

You should have success if you use `python -m virtualenv myprojectenv` (in python 2.) or `python -m venv myprojectenv` in python3. That will call python and the module (the -m) called virtualenv.

That will create the virtual environment folder in the directory that your powershell is currently at. So if your powershell is at C:\users\xxx>, it'll make it there. So you should make sure to navigate to where you want before you make it.

Edit: adding versions

Comment: Thanks you very much