# error during installation of virtual environment

Tags: django, virtual

I face with folliowing error when I want to install virtual env:
C:\Users\MICROSOFT\Desktop\django_project>virtualenv venv
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

How it could be tackled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950740/virtualenv-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-prog)